# Ethers.js equivalent for web3.eth.getStorageAt?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, testing, ethers.js

I want to check a private state variable with ethers.js. What is the equivalent for `web3.eth.getStorageAt` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's also getStorageAt you can find the doc [here](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getStorageAt). It's exposed as a provider method in ethers.js so something in the line of :

```
await provider.getStorageAt(address, slot);
```

Answer (score 4):

In Ethers V6 it's now [getStorage](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/#Provider-getStorage)

```
await provider.getStorage(address, slot);
```